# Why can't I declare generic List<T> as return type for interface method?

Tags: c#

Why can't I create an interface method with return type `List<T>`? I'm encountering this compile error "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found"

```
interface ILoader 
{        
    List<T> LoadValues();
}
```

Appreciate any of your input.

Comment: Further to the answers below, it's probably better to return `IList<T>` instead. Gives users of your interface more flexibility about the concrete type of what they return.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is `T` supposed to be in your interface? For the compiler, `T` is just an unknown identifier at that point.

You need to specify something for `T`, some type that is used as the type argument for `List<T>`.

---

Depending on what you want to achieve, there are four options:

- Declare `T` as a generic parameter on the interface/class level:

  ```
  interface ILoader<T>
  {        
      List<T> LoadValues();
  }
  ```
- Declare `T` as a generic parameter on the method level:

  ```
  interface ILoader
  {        
      List<T> LoadValues<T>();
  }
  ```
- Assign a fixed type as `T`; e.g. `int` (w.l.o.g.):

  ```
  interface ILoader
  {        
      List<int> LoadValues();
  }
  ```
- Declare `T` as a generic parameter on a higher nesting level (thanks to [Jeppe Stig Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336654/jeppe-stig-nielsen) for pointing out this possibility):

  ```
  class Outer<T>
  {
      interface ILoader
      {
          List<T> LoadValues();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: @siride: Thanks for the edit. I couldn't figure out why my code wasn't properly formatted, but apparently one requires an extra indentation for code in enumeration items :-)

Comment: Yeah, go figure. I almost edited your formatting to put the opening braces where they belong, on the line with the declaration, but I figured that would be going too far ;).

Comment: @siride: "where they belong" ... not according to most C# styleguides I've seen. In Java, it'd be a different story, though ;-)

Comment: I plan to return List<string> and/or List<int> in interface method implementation. Therefore I want to declare the argument for return type as unknown.

Comment: @kyi12321: the only other option in that case is to have the method return the non-generic IList (or IEnumerable, ICollection, etc.)

Comment: Braces where they belong? Put the entire type & member declaration on the same line or go home! >_>

Comment: @kyi12321: Then the first or the second option will be more appropriate. Please refine your question or create a follow-up question if you need more information on this.

Comment: Of course, in the unlikely case that the `ILoader` interface is nested inside some generic `class` or `struct`, there's a fourth possibility: The return value could be `List<TOutside>` where `TOutside` is one of the type parameters ("generic parameters") of that containing class/stuct.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Thank you, I updated my answer to also include that option.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input.

Answer (score 2):

The T generic parameter must also be declared in the interface. Something like this:

```
interface ILoader<T>
{        
    List<T> LoadValues();
}
```

Comment: Or you can put the `T` in the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
interface ILoader<T>
{
    List<T> LoadValues();
}
```

Or

```
interface ILoader
{        
    List<T> LoadValues<T>();
}
```

Or even, possibly:

```
interface ILoader 
{        
    List<dynamic> LoadValues();
}
```

^Isn't the best idea but usable.